# Is it possible to use classes in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am specifically asking about programming in Google's Code Editor of the Earth Engine.

I copy-pasted the example class from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_classes.asp)

```
class Car {
  constructor(brand) {
    this.carname = brand;
  }
}
mycar = new Car("Ford");
```

and it gives me the following error:

```
SyntaxError: The keyword 'class' is reserved (2:0)
```

This is confusing because I would have expected `"class" is not defined in this scope.`, if it would not have supported classes, but the error seems to suggest that `class` is recognised, but I'm misusing it.

Any suggestions on how to use classes in Google Earth Engine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classes were introduced in ES6 (ECMAScript 2015), which the code editor unfortunately doesn't support. I really, really wish it did!

According to [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/308081/26474), which is authoritative, coming from Google, the code editor is based on [Caja, which only supports ES5 strict mode](https://developers.google.com/caja).

It is unclear why Caja reserves the `class` keyword, perhaps for future compatibility.

Looking at [Caja's code on github](https://github.com/google/caja), there seems to be no plans to ever update Caja to ES6.

Answer (score 0):

In fact you can, you just need to trick ES5 into thinking your function are objects. This is more or less what they use in the source code of earthengine-api itself.

For you example it would look like:

```js
var Car = function(brand) {
  //members
  this.carname = brand;

  // methods
  this.display(){
    print(this.carname);
  };
};

var car1 = New Car("Ford")
var car2 = New Car("Citroën")
```

exmaple in the code editor: https://code.earthengine.google.com/f5ebc6467a2ad04e5f0efde1ce16cc0f